# Using C# reflection to make a Generic List of Controllers derived of the same baseclass

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

In order to prevent the generation of new identical lines of code, I wanted to retrieve all the fields / properties of the same class and iterate over it in order to execute their functions.

This way, if we need to add more menus to the UIsystem ( MenuControllers) we just need to add the declaration line of the new menu.

Lets write the example code

**Main class**

```
public class MenuSystem : UISystem
{
  public MainMenuController _mainMenuCtrl;
  public PlayerMenuController _playerMenuCtrl;
  public StoreMenuController  _storeMenuCtrl;
  public ...

  //This is what I want
  private IList<MenuController<BaseMenu>> _menuList;

  private const BindingFlags Flags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public;
  private void InitializeAllMenus()
  {
     //This is how it looks like now
     _mainMenuCtrl.RetrieveMenuInfo();
     _playerMenuCtrl.RetrieveMenuInfo();
     _storeMenuCtrl.RetrieveMenuInfo();

     //****WHAT I WANT TO DO*****
    
     foreach(var menu in _menuList)
     {
        menu.RetrieveMenuInfo();
     }
   }

     private void DisposeAllMenus()
  {
     //This is how it looks like now
     _mainMenuCtrl.Dispose();
     _playerMenuCtrl.Dispose();
     _storeMenuCtrl.Dispose();

     //****WHAT I WANT TO DO*****
    
     foreach(var menu in _menuList)
     {
        menu.Dispose();
     }
   }
}
```

***MenuControllers Definitions***

```
public MainMenuController: MenuController<MainMenu>
{
    public Show();
    public Hide();
    public OnBackButtonClicked();
    ...

}
```

```
public PlayerMenuController : MenuController<PlayerMenu>
{
    public Show();
    public Hide();
    public OnBackButtonClicked();
    ...
}
```

...etc

***MenuController Class***

```
public abstract class MenuController<T> where T : BaseMenu
{
   public void RetrieveMenuInfo() {...}
   public void Dispose() {...}
}
```

I've tried something like this ( and much more to be honest but I think this is enough)

```
private void FillMenuList()
{
     ***Retrieving fields, Option 1***
       var fieldList = GetType().GetFields(Flags)
                 .Select(var => var.GetValue(this));
    
     ***Retrieving fields, Option 2***
       var fieldList = GetType().GetFields(Flags)
                 .Select(var => var.GetValue(this)).OfType<MenuController<BaseMenu>;
  

}
```

OPTION1 of the function above retrieve the fields of the `MenuSystem` class  correctly as `IEnumerable<object>`
but Option 2 with `IEnumerable<MenuController<BaseMenu>>` does not retrieve any field.

Our main trouble here is that we cannot fill a list/array with all those types/derived-types to iterate over it.

I really hope its enough with this info. I'm quite newbie using reflection.

I managed to do this before in other parts of the code but with no generics involved

Thanks a lot!

Comment: why not just let all your classes implement a common interface that defines `RetrieveMenuInfo`?

Comment: Yes, thanks. I guess this is the best solution. I did a quick test and despite it means that we need to change some basecode, this way will be better and faster to implement. 

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can try using GetType().GetProperties() on the object, then for each property do item.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0].FullName, this will give you the generic class name. Then you can cast that to the class that you need and get all the fields data.

I hope this helps.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).